# TypeError: Modelname.findById is not a function with sequelize nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to find value from table with respect to Id passed in api. When using  findByID to find one record I am getting below errro.

```
TypeError: Modelname.findById is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findById` is from old version of Sequelize module. Now they are using `findByPk` to find single record from table .

example: `Book.findByPk(someId)`